# Control reached end of function without RETURN

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have this function in `PostgreSQL` and when I'm trying to execute it, I get this error message:

> ERROR:  control reached end of function without RETURN
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "SA_PRJ".usp_add_timesheet_record_neww(integer,integer,numeric,numeric,character varying,character varying)

I'm not sure but I think the return is the problem, must have return at the end?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SA_PRJ".usp_add_timesheet_record_neww(p_uid integer, p_project_id integer, p_allocated_time numeric, p_achieved_time numeric, p_task_desc character varying, p_obs character varying)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
declare alloc_id integer;
declare project integer;
declare allocated integer;
declare allocated_time numeric;
BEGIN

    project := p_project_id;

    allocated_time := (SELECT SUM(fld_allocated_time)
    FROM "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet
    WHERE fld_project_id = project);

    allocated := (SELECT fld_allocated_days FROM "SD_PRJ".tbl_project where fld_id = project);

    if not "SA_ADM".usp_check_permission(p_uid, 'SA_PRJ', 'usp_add_timesheet_record') then
    raise exception 'User ID % nu are permisii pentru aceasta operatie!', p_uid;
    end if;

    select fld_id into alloc_id from "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_allocation where fld_emp_id = p_uid and fld_project_id = p_project_id;

    BEGIN
    IF (allocated > allocated_time) THEN

    INSERT INTO "SD_PRJ".tbl_project_timesheet(fld_emp_id, fld_project_id, fld_is_allocated,fld_allocated_time, fld_achieved_time, fld_task_desc, fld_obs)
    VALUES (p_uid,p_project_id,coalesce(alloc_id,0), p_allocated_time, p_achieved_time,p_task_desc, p_obs);
    RAISE NOTICE 'OK';

    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Not OK!';
    END IF;
    END;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Thanks.

Comment: As the error message said, you've defined a return value and there's no return statement in your function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either define the function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SA_PRJ".usp_add_timesheet_record_neww(p_uid integer, p_project_id integer, p_allocated_time numeric, p_achieved_time numeric, p_task_desc character varying, p_obs character varying)
RETURNS void AS
...
```

or you use `RETURN` instead of `RAISE NOTICE` (if thats what you want to return)

Comment: I used RETURN insted of RAISE NOTICE.Thanks @Robert

Comment: This also  happens when you try to return the value before end of parent or single transaction , so make a child transaction first and then return and end the parent begin block. like this below.
declare
begin
save := false;
-- code for initilaization
begin
-- Code for child transaction 
save := true;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE NOTICE 'No Records Found!';commit;

   end;
   
  return save;

  end;

Answer (score 0):

I created the [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) which returns nothing against `RETURNS INTEGER` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$                     -- ↑ Here ↑
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, calling `my_func()` got the same error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  control reached end of function without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_func()
```

So, I set `RETURN 2;` to `my_func()` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN 2; -- Here
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------
       2
(1 row)
```

Or, I replaced `RETURNS INTEGER` with `RETURNS VOID` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID
AS $$                     -- ↑ Here ↑
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, I could call `my_func()` without error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
 my_func
---------

(1 row)
```